# Echo all directory with php ftp function starting with

Tags: php, ftp, directory

Is there an way in php to use the ftp function te echo all directory **starting** with '20110508'?

So it wil list:
'20110508 abcde'
'20110508 fghi'
'20110508 jklm'
etc.

Comment: maybe i am reading it wrong but lookup opendir and readdir

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ftp_nlist` function to retrieve file list of specified diretory, then fetch through this array and filter items by comparing with desired mask 
e.g.

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
foreach($contents as $f)
  if (substr($f, 0, 8)=='20110508') {
    echo $f;
  }
```

Comment: This gives me an error: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: i've edited the sample code. i hope you don't pass the ftp_nlist result right to substr function as first param?

Comment: Thx for helping me out @heximal. The error is gone, but no results are displayed.

Comment: do you realize that $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); will return the files list of the current directory? is there any files? especially starting with '20110508'? to scan for particular directory you should sprecify it as the parameter of ftp_nlist function (instead of ".")

Comment: No I don't, when logged into the ftp there should be an folder selcted, 2011 for this year. In this folder I'm looking for one starting with an number like 20110508